# How to make Twitter Bootstrap Collapse work on dynamically loaded html using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am loading html using javascript call, this html has Bootstrap Collapse.

```
<li class="dd-item" data-id="home">
<div id="panel1" class="panel panel-default panel-collapsed">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-actions">
            <a role="button" data-collapse="#panel1"  class="btn btn-sm btn-icon">
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="panel-title">Home</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you give an specific explanation of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#id"` are what you need to be able your bootstrap will work, `data-toggle="collapse"` will tell bootstrap for a collapse function while `data-target="#text"` point to the `id` of html tag
that will perform toggle collapse.

In you code, replace this line,

```
  <a role="button" data-collapse="#panel1"  class="btn btn-sm btn-icon">
```

with

```
  <a role="button" data-collapse="#panel1"  class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text">
```

where `#text` is the `div` ID. In your

```
  <div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
```

remove this inline css style `style="display: none;"` and put an id attribute `id="#text"` for example. Look like this,

```
<div id="text" class="collapse panel-body">
```

And there you go.